# Is NSMutableArray can be editing or move indexPath when data is from URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios, nsmutablearray

I load data from URL to a NSMutableArray ,like this code :

```
NSMutableArray *mArray;
mArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theNewURL];
```

If I load this array and show on tableview

Can I move the row index and edit the table view ,ex.delete ... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can remove the item from the array and reload the tableView

```
NSMutableArray * mArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theNewURL];
[mArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}Can I remove item in this method ?

Comment: in this method you can change the index of table cell with others cell , but item will never delete

Comment: Like if you use move cell then you can replace ur indexpath cell with any indecpath and other cell move accroding to index path for example

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        rowNumber = indexPath.row;

        UIActionSheet *registerActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sure You Want To Delete?"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

        registerActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

        [registerActionSheet showInView:self.view];

        [registerActionSheet release];

        // delete your data item here
        // Animate the deletion from the table.
        //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Comment: this is for delete right ?I will try it , but still no idea about movie the cells